# Java application not reading from file when executing command with Runtime.getRuntime()

Tags: java, runtime, filereader

I have a Java app that executes a command using `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("command");` Then it generates a file which I need to read to find a string, everything ok so far.

The problem is that the program can't find a given string after executing the command, but if I comment out the line `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("command");` after I run the app the first time and further runs and the file is created it finds the string properly. Seems like `getRuntime()` is stopping from work the `fileReader` for some reason. Anyone knows a fix for this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    String[] command = new String[3];
    command[0] = "cmd.exe";
    command[1] = "/c";
    command[2] = "C:\\Users\\kjdah\\Desktop\\handle.exe -a > C:\\Users\\kjdah\\Desktop\\handles.txt";

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    String toFind = "##?#USB#VID_04F2&PID_B2E1&MI_00#6&9f9977c&0&0000#";
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\kjdah\\Desktop\\handles.txt");

    boolean found = false;
    String strLinePid = null;

    try {
        FileReader fstream = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(fstream);
        String strLine;

        while ((strLine = buffer.readLine()) != null)   {

            if(strLine.contains("pid:")){
                strLinePid = strLine;
            }

            if(strLine.contains(toFind)){
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        buffer.close();
        fstream.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("An error happened: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Runtime#exec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-) creates a new process that runs concurrently. You have to wait for it to finish for processing its result.

This can be done using the method [`Process#waitFor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--) of the `Process` that `Runtime#exec` returns. Additionally, it is a good idea to check if the process was successful. Have a look at the [Javadoc of `Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) for more information.

Comment: That was fast! Nice one mm759 I just saved the process and added the .waitfor(); it worked. You made my day, cheers! ;)